# 8788v2 Browse button does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

Since updating to 8788v2 patch the Browse button does not work. I have checked and the swf files have now been deleted. And now the Browse button does not seem to work.Is there a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try to flush the cache ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and its not fixed it. I have reindexed and tried in Incognito. Seems to work fine on the Catalog I am able to Browse for an Image and that works.

Comment: Check your browser console for an error. Presumably when you click the 'Browse' button, nothing happens at all?

Comment: Mage version pls

Comment: yes the console is not showing any errors. Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: Is there a work around I could use? Or I was thinking of adding those swf files in. Would this be okay?

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed - Image Upload issue after PATCH 8788 install of Magento version CE 1.7.0.2 - 1.9.2.4.**

> `I was able to fix it,Please Follow following instruction.`
>
> Step >> 1: After installed security patch 8788 successfully, Please go to admin panel and **flush all Magento cache**. Then **Logout your Admin Panel** and **Relogin to Admin Panel**.
>
> Step >> 2: **Go to Index Management** and select all **reindex all data** after **flush all Magento cache once again**.
>
> Step >> 3: ***This very Important step,*** **Delete your browser cache(Ctrl+shift+Delete) history clear all browsing data from browser including cookies.**
>
> Step >> 4: Go to Catalog >> Product Management , **add new image of any product,now you can see everything work fine.**

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but in case anyone is looking for a solution when browser is not throwing any console errors, check if you have Dull Uploader installed and disable or remove it.

This solved it for me.